# libssh2_scp_recv is not populating struct stat

Tags: c, ssh, scp, libssh2

I can successfully send files from one end to another using
`libssh2_scp_send()`. When I try to receive files using
`libssh2_scp_recv()`, though, it does not fill the `struct stat`
parameter with data. The file size always returns "0".

```
struct stat    file_info;

LIBSSH2_CHANNEL *channel = libssh2_scp_recv( session, source_file, &file_info );

printf( "file_info.st_size = %lu.\n",       file_info.st_size );
```

Any other fields in `file_info` come empty too, even though `channel` is not NULL.

My session is opened correctly and works for any other SSH operation
(running remote comands, sending files...)

I am using "libssh2-1.3.0".

Is there any clue, please?

Really thanks.

---

EDIT:

I changed the third line to:

```
fprintf( stderr, "** file_info { st_size = %lu; st_atime = %lu }. SSH last error = %d",
    file_info.st_size, file_info.st_atime,
    libssh2_session_last_errno( info->session ) );
```

And the result is:

```
** file_info { st_size = 0; st_atime = 0 }. SSH last error = 0`.
```

That's it. The returned channel is valid, I can read from it. `libssh2_session_last_errno()` gives no error, but `st_size` still comes empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some error checking, so we can see exactly what's going on:

```
channel = libssh2_scp_recv(session, path_to_file, &struct_stat);
if (!channel && (libssh2_session_last_errno(session) != LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN)) 
{
    if ((struct_stat.st_mode == 0) && (struct_stat.st_atime == 0) && \
           (struct_stat.st_mtime == 0) && (struct_stat.st_size == 0)) 
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "No file found and the error %d\n", \
                     libssh2_session_last_errno(session));

       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

Hope this help.

Regards.

Comment: This will allow me a more precise diagnostic, but does not explain why `st_size == 0` even knowing that the file exists and has data. If I try to read the file until no more bytes, I can read it correctly.

Comment: @JaxWR : what return this libssh2_session_last_errno(session)?

Comment: `** file_info { st_size = 0; st_atime = 0 }. SSH last error = 0`. Thats it. The returned channel is valid and there is no `errno` for `libssh2_session_last_errno()`.

Answer (score 0):

Only Change Time and Permission modes of source_file are being populated by libssh2_scp_recv(session, source_file, &file_info) on my system. Therefore,  file_info.st_ctim.tv_sec and file_info.st_mode have valid values.

If you look at the libssh2 API documentation for libssh2_scp_recv, http://libssh2.sourceforge.net/doc/#libssh2scprecv, it does not guarantee that all fields of file_info will be populated.

The end of file is indicated by a single NULL(0) byte being returned by libssh2_channel_read.